# Very strange NSPredicate behavior when logging

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I'm trying to create a predicate to sort an array of objects that have a date property.  However, when I try to NSLog the predicate, an exception is raised and I get a strange error.

Here's the code:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSDate * minDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ ", minDate];
NSLog(predicate);
```

Here's the error:

```
2012-02-04 12:45:58.400 MyApp[42746:17303] -[NSComparisonPredicate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9359000
```

So, why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the exact type of property you're trying to apply the predicate to?

Comment: NSDate.  But, I'm not even getting to the place where I actually use the predicate.

Comment: I'm not sure comparing NSDates with such a predicate will work. And yes, you can't use NSLog() like that.

Comment: I think, the predicate itself is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try: `NSLog(@"%@", predicate)`

NSLog expects a NSString, that works as an format string. The number of format specifiers in the format string will specify, how many arguments need to follow.

from the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIJAAIA):

> **NSLog**
>   Logs an error message to the Apple System Log facility.
>
> ```
> void NSLog (
>    NSString *format,
>    ...
> );
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>   Simply calls NSLogv, passing it a variable number of
>   arguments.